# Create templates for wiki pages and place it in the drop-down-menu

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-template

Is it possible to create templates for pages? And how do I add them to the drop-down menu?

[image: drop-down]

I know that there is a possibility - at least for Word documents. Unfortunately, I couldn't find it yet.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint, you will need to first [create a content type](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-or-customize-a-site-content-type-27eb6551-9867-4201-a819-620c5658a60f) which uses the page you need as template. Then [add the content type to your library](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-a-content-type-to-a-list-or-library-917366ae-f7a2-47ad-87a5-9689a1884e60).

A SharePoint content type pulls together an item and information about the item. The item might be one of many different kinds of files, a document, an excel workbook, or even a status indicator for a progress report. It could also be a list or a folder. A content type associates this item with key metadata or other information such as a template or a retention policy.

For example, you can define a Sales Contract content type, and add it to the library that your team uses. Then, any time someone wants to create a sales proposal, they just choose Sales Contract from the New Document menu.

For what is content type, please check this:[Introduction to content types and content type publishing](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/introduction-to-content-types-and-content-type-publishing-e1277a2e-a1e8-4473-9126-91a0647766e5)